# Is lockmode PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT supported for all database engines including postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Going through the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html

`The persistence implementation must support use of locks of type LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE on a non-versioned entity as well as on a versioned entity.`

This implies that LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is dependent on persistence implementation. I am interested in LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT - my guess is the same limitation will apply on that. I am unable to find any documentation to give the list of databases that support this lock mode. I am currently using **postgres** database. Will the lock mode work for me as expected?

Comment: It will depend on your JPA provider's implementation of that as well as the database. Not all providers have support for all DBs. The main ones certainly support Postgres, and Postgres does have support for it - PESSIMISTIC_READs are akin to 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE', while PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is expected DB row level locking within a transaction.

Comment: hi @Chris - thanks for your input. I am aware of PESSIMISTIC_WRITE but the question is about PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT for postgres

Comment: Again, it depends on the implementation. The wording of the spec/javadoc though pretty much states that PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is just going to immediately increment the version field on your entity - so isn't anything more than PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Comment: hi @Chris, I have been able to verify PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is supported on postgres. However, there is one peculiar observation, PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock can be taken with and without nowait option, however PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is taking lock with nowait option only. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: You should probably ask a question on it - I'd guess you are using Hibernate as I don't know of a no-wait option in JPA. Maybe you are trying to use  javax.persistence.lock.timeout query hint? It is up to the JPA provider on how and if it can be supported against the database, and yours may have overlooked it for the PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT option - or they might have thought the entity state would be inconsistent afterward so intentionally left it out.

Comment: Thanks, will ask a separate question. I have set the hints appropriately - as I have been able to implement PESSIMISTIC_WRITE both with wait and no wait. But PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is only taking nowait lock, irrespective of hints